# AVFoundation videoZoomFactor not working (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

All of the camera tweaks I am wanting to use are working except the zoomfactor. I am lost as to why this is happening...any ideas? The custom exposure and focus settings work fine. Did something change in iOS that im not aware of?

```
captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    do{
        do{
            try device?.lockForConfiguration()
            device?.setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition(focusValue, completionHandler: {(time) -> Void in})
            device?.setExposureModeCustomWithDuration(CMTimeMake(1, exposureValue), iso: ISOValue, completionHandler: {(time) -> Void in})
            let zoomFactor:CGFloat = 16
            device?.videoZoomFactor = zoomFactor
            device?.unlockForConfiguration()

        }catch{
            print(error)
        }

        stillImageOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
        if(captureSession.canAddInput(input)){
            captureSession.addInput(input)
            if(captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput)){
                captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

                captureSession.startRunning()
                let captureVideoLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.init(session: captureSession)
                captureVideoLayer.frame = self.previewView.bounds
                captureVideoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                self.previewView.layer.insertSublayer(captureVideoLayer, at: 0)
            }
        }
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: i still think videozoomfactor is broken in ios11. can anyone verify?

Answer (score 3):

turns out i was just setting my device settings at the wrong point. If the lockconfig try block is moved below the capture session stuff it then works as intended.

Comment: yep that was it ! Thank you very much ! See the location of my videoZoomFactor code in the answer below (for Swift-4.2 / Xcode 9.0, iOS 11.0 SDK)

Answer (score 3):

Using Apple's example code for Photo & Video Acquisition (i.e. AVFoundation), I tried to change the device-zoom of my iPhone camera in code.

With the help of [user2345335](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2345335/user2345335), I realised that the code-location where you place your zoom manipulation properties matters - and also, make sure you use `device.lockForConfiguration()` prior to any videoDevice manipulation ! Both are important (code-location and locking !!).

Here the Link and a screenshot to see the download-button where the original Apple example can be taken from :

([AVFoundation Apple Code example: Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html))

[image]

Here is the code excerpt of the original Apple example with MY CODE THAT MANIPULATES THE ZOOM inserted at the correct spot :)

(Swift-4.2 / Xcode 10.0, iOS 11.0 SDK)

```
// Call this on the session queue.
private func configureSession() {
    if setupResult != .success {
        return
    }

    // ... missing original code (not important for this illustration)...

    // Add video input.
    do {
        var defaultVideoDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

        // ... missing original code (not important for this illustration)...

        if session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) {
            session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
            self.videoDeviceInput = videoDeviceInput

            // ... missing original code (not important for this illustration)...

        } else {
            print("Could not add video device input to the session")
            setupResult = .configurationFailed
            session.commitConfiguration()
            return
        }

        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! MY CODE THAT MANIPULATES THE ZOOM  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! PLACE IT HERE AND ZOOM WILL WORK !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        guard let device = defaultVideoDevice else { return }
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            defer { device.unlockForConfiguration() }
            device.videoZoomFactor = 10.0
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!! END OF MY CODE THAT MANIPULATES THE ZOOM  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    } catch {
        print("Could not create video device input: \(error)")
        setupResult = .configurationFailed
        session.commitConfiguration()
        return
    }

    // Add audio input.
    do {
        let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
        let audioDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)

        if session.canAddInput(audioDeviceInput) {
            session.addInput(audioDeviceInput)
        } else {
            print("Could not add audio device input to the session")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not create audio device input: \(error)")
    }

    // Add photo output.
    if session.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {
        session.addOutput(photoOutput)

        photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
        photoOutput.isLivePhotoCaptureEnabled = photoOutput.isLivePhotoCaptureSupported
        photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliverySupported
        livePhotoMode = photoOutput.isLivePhotoCaptureSupported ? .on : .off
        depthDataDeliveryMode = photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliverySupported ? .on : .off

    } else {
        print("Could not add photo output to the session")
        setupResult = .configurationFailed
        session.commitConfiguration()
        return
    }

    session.commitConfiguration()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced an issue  with zoom factor not working on some devices (usualy the newer ones with wide lens camera) when `output.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled` was not set and therefore the default value was `true` . The problem was present only when `AVCaptureSession.Preset` was set to `.photo`.